# How can I make Isotope images responsive?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

Anybody know how I can make Isotope images responsive?

i add this simple css code :

```
img { height: auto; max-width:100%; }
```

and this code work on any images except isotope items ( images ) !

Comment: By isotope image you mean http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/help.html#images ?